# Centos Will No Longer Forward Port 80

Tags: iptables, port-forwarding

I have been using iptables to do port forwarding since it's inception.  For some reason after a reboot the ability to forward port 80 on a Centos server is broken.  I even updated from Centos 7.7 to 8.  I can forward other ports, but not 80.  Firewalld and SELINUX are disabled.  HTTP is set to ACCEPT as it has been.

The iptables line is:

```
$IPTABLES -t nat -A PREROUTING --dst (public address) -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.x.x.x
```

I have also tried adding :80 to the end of the internal server's address with no success.

Again,  I can forward other ports successfully.  I have tried forwarding to different internal servers so it's not the machine I am forwarding to.

Any ideas?

Thanks,
Robert

Comment: Are you on a business class Internet connection?  Is your ISP blocking incoming port 80?  What happens if you install/run tcpdump?  Can you see any incoming port 80 requests?  `tcpdump -qni any port 80`

Comment: Yes, business class with fixed IP.  They are not blocking port 80.  I will try tcpdump.  Thanks.

Comment: BTW,  under 7.7 I temporarily added Apache and was able to access it via the public ip.

Comment: What is your FORWARD policy and if needed - do you have appropriate forwarding rule allowing the forwarded traffic? Is your forwarded connection leaving on the interface at which it arrived or on a different one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to change which interface(two nics on the same subnet) on the server had the default gateway.  I suspect this was due to a network component update as it had been working for two years as it was.

Thanks folks,
Robert

Answer (score 0):

Try `-I` instead of `-A` in the case of an already existing rules.

Look your nat iptables rules, and verify that number of packets increase on the good rule with :

```
iptables -t nat -L -n -v
```

Then delete the bad rule with `-D`

Comment: Tried iptables -t nat -L -n -v and sometimes it looks like some packets are going to the webserver but no page loads.  I tried it with two different webservers internally that can be accessed from the internal network.  Will try -I . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

RHEL 8 (and CentOS is following RHEL) is moving with firewall support to nftables. Additionally they also use firewalld and it may overwrite whatever iptables you've put in place if/when enabled.

Please check what firewall SW you have installed and enabled and disable whatever is beyond what you use - they WILL interfere with each other.

Comment: Firewalld is removed and selinux is disabled.  I flush the rules before loading mine.  Thanks.